# Detecting single character in string

Tags: c, string, matrix, stdin, detection

So, I'm trying to detect a single character in a string. There must be no other characters besides whitespace and a null character. This is my first issue, as my code detects the character in a string with other characters (besides the whitespace).

My second issue, is I can't seem to figure out how best to read matrices from a file. I'm supposed to read the first line and get the ROWS x COLUMNS. Then I'm supposed to read the data into the a matrix array that is stored globally. Then reading the second matrix into a second matrix array (stored globally as well).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

typedef struct matrixStruct{
    int rows;
    int columns; 
}matrixStruct;

typedef int bool;
enum{
    false,
    true
};

/*
 * 
 */
int aMatrix1[10][10];
int aMatrix2[10][10];
int multiMatrix[10][10];


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE *inputFile;
    char tempLine[MAXLINE], *tempChar, *tempString;
    char *endChar;
    endChar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    (*endChar) = '*';
    bool readFile = true;



inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(inputFile == NULL){
    printf("File %s not found.\n", argv[1]);
    perror("Error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}else{
    printf("File opened!\n");
}

int numRow, numColumn, i, j, tempNum, count = 0;


do{
    fgets(tempLine, MAXLINE, inputFile);
    tempChar = strchr(tempLine, '*');
    if(tempChar != NULL){
        printf("True @ %s\ncount=%d\n",tempChar,count);
        readFile = false;
    }else{
        sscanf(tempLine, "%d %d", &numRow, &numColumn);
        count++;
        for(i=0;i<numRow;i++){
            fgets(tempLine, MAXLINE, inputFile);
            for(j=0;j<numColumn;j++){

                aMatrix1[i][j] = atoi(tempNum);
            }
        }
    }
}
while(readFile);

printf("aMatrix1[%d][%d]= \n", numRow, numColumn);
for(i=0; i < numRow;i++){
        for(j=0; j < numColumn; j++){
            printf("aMatrix[%d][%d] = %d\t", i, j, aMatrix1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: for the first issue : why you don't use Regular Expression ?                 And for the second issue : you can always use ReadFile to access file data binary .

Comment: Like a while loop to move through the tempLine array (string) and if not whitespace or the character detection, then escape?

I don't understand what you mean by access the data binary?

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue you could do what you suggested in your comment (regexp are an overkill here) - loop through the string, break on any non-whitespace char that's not what you expect, and count the ones that do match - you don't want 0 matches, and i guess also no more than 1.

However, I suggest you read the man page for strtok - I normally wouldn't suggest it as it's not thread-safe and has strange behaviors, but in this simple case it could work fine - provide whitespace chars as delimiters, and it would return the first non-whitespace string. If that's doesn't strcmp with "*", or if the next call to strtok doesn't return null, then it's not a match.

By the way - what do you plan to do with lines that aren't " .. * .. " or " ROWS x COLUMNS "? you're not handling them right now.

As for the second issue - strtok again could come to the rescue - repeated calls would just give you the whitespace-delimited numbers (as strings), and you'll be able to populate tempNum for each iteration.